# Mac image browser recommendation, not looking like a Windows application

Tags: osx, image-viewer

I have used XnViewMP for years but I am still not used to its UI, it looks like a Windows application a lot.

I tried Pixea but it even lacks delete function so when I use it to browser my pictures and hit one I don't look I have to switch to finder to delete it! (lol)

I am trying Picsee now, but I  am still learning its design logic, e.g. I just want to open a folder and see all the pictures in it. But with Picsee I am not sure what is "correct" way to do that.

So any recommendation for image browser on Mac ?